# Deleting Multiple Rows in a MySQL Database using PHP PDO extension

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am using bellow MYSQL query to delete single records from table and working perfect for me  but how to write for multiple records with IN operator.

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM reg WHERE id = :id";
$query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(':id' => $id));
```

For example I have ids from array like `$id = array(23,24);` and I have treid with loop like bellow but not worked :(

```
for($i=0; $i<count($id); $i++) {
    $id = $id[$i];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM $table_name WHERE id = :$id";
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(':id' => $id));

}
```

I hope you understand my question and hope you will help me.

Thanks.

Comment: you are over-writing $id inside the loop so use `$query->execute(array(':id' => $id[$i]));` and remove the line `$id = $id[$i];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for($i=0; $i<count($id); $i++) {
    $sql = "DELETE FROM $table_name WHERE id = :id";
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(':id' => $id[$i]));
}
```

Comment: For future reference it's usually helpful to add a few words of text to your answers, explaining how/why your solution fixes it. (Remember that people will find this question via search engines for years to come)